# Can we adjust the points and privileges system a bit?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

I feel like I have been trying to be a good stackexchange citizen, but have been stymied by the points system.

The one example I have right now is that it requires 150 reputation points to create new tags. Surely, it's better to allow people to create bad tags than it is to require that people get this much reputation. I had other examples previously, but this one seemed particularly too high.

I assume these are listed somewhere, but I can't find them. Can we change this one, and look more closely at some of the others?

Also, I just tried to tag this with "reputation," but got bit by the same problem. Oh, irony...

Comment: The [Stack Exchange FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/faq) tells how many points you must have to earn each ability. I don't think it's accurate, though, because I gained the ability to edit posts at only 1000 rep. points.

Comment: @mac9416: [Our FAQ](http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/faq) has still lower reputation requirements since we are still in beta. I think the numbers are iteratively increased when enough people are at certain ranges.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the Beta the points system is on a sliding scale. As most of us were able to create tags prior to 150 points. Ans while in Beta that makes sense because not every tag has been thought of.

Though I think the system as worked out rather well on the other StackExchange sites and I envision it would work well here.

Answer (score 3):

In short, this isn't going to happen. On StackOverflow and the other parts of the trilogy, you now need 1500 rep to create a new tag - read this [blog post about the reasoning](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/).

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a good idea... It will stop duplicate tags and really long tags ect. and trolls may make new tags for bad... even more ect.

In other words it is only there to stop trolls!!!